# client.execute not responding in android

Tags: android

I try every possible solution but application crash when code reach to client.execute and in exception it just jump to catch and end normally but have no response

```
 public static String getUrlResponse(String url) {
    try {
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        return convertStreamToString1(entity.getContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}

private static String convertStreamToString1(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),8 * 1024);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and this is exception

02-18 15:43:13.246    1951-1951/com.example.munawarhussain.alphacar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.munawarhussain.alphacar, PID: 1951
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: So what does the exception say?

Comment: Did you add internet permission in manifest?

Comment: yes i add internet permission

Comment: One Important Warning, @Munawar  Network Operations Are Not Allowed On main UI thread , so if you do this method call on your activity's main thread , you  will have error , taking  out  your method to inside an **AsyncTask** will solve the problem .see AsyncTask         link]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@katmanco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218551/katmanco) 
Operations Are Not Allowed On main UI thread , so if you do this method call on your activity's main thread , you will have error , taking out your method to inside an AsyncTask will solve the problem .see AsyncTask link]developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

First which exception is you got, print that in catch block so you can know what's the problem.